# Convert int to date and assign to variable

Tags: sas

How to convert `20011015` into a date and assign it to a global variable?

My attempts have failed along these lines:

```
%global var;
%local var=20011015;
data _NULL_
  call symputx('mydate', put(&var., yymmdd8.), 'G');
run;
%put &mydate.
```

Currently `mydate` is empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your purpose, use the statement that you find best.

```
%let var = 20011015;

data _null_;
   call symputx('mydate', input(put(&var., 8.), yymmdd8.), 'g');
   call symputx('mydate2', put(&var., 8.), 'g');
run;

%put &=mydate.;
%put &=mydate2.;
```